# Is this possible with a regex?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to have a regex matcher that matches on the following:
I need to know if there is *any* substring that is both inside AND outside matching parenthesis, exactly formatted as `(@ ... )`

Examples of match:

- `abc (@ abc )`
- `abc (@ (& abc ) )`
- `abc (& def (@ abc ) )`
- `(& (& abc def ) (@ abc ) )`
- `(& def (& abc ) (@ abc ) )`

Examples of **no** match:

- `abc`
- `(@ abc )`
- `abc (@ def )`
- `abc (& abc)`

*Edit:*
Here's the rspec specification to check the regex. Only 2 tests fail:

"(@ abc ) abc" should match

"(@ abc ) (@ abc )" should not match

```
describe "regex" do

  let(:regex) { /(.+).*\(@.*\1.*\)/ }

  matches = ["abc (@ abc )", "(@ abc ) abc", "abc (@ (& abc ) )", "abc (@ (& abc ) )"]
  no_matches = ["abc", "(@ abc )", "abc def", "abc abc", "abc (& abc)", "(@ abc ) (@ abc)"]

  matches.each do |flow|
    it "should match '#{flow}'" do
      flow.should match regex
    end
  end

  no_matches.each do |flow|
    it "should not match '#{flow}'" do
      flow.should_not match regex
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: what about `(@@ abc) (@ abc)`, `(abc (@ abc))`, `(@ abc (@ abc)` ? i suppose you will never have to parse these strings but better be sure

Comment: and what about `(@ abc (abc)) (@ abc)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use regex pattern

```
/(?=.*?(?<!@ )(\b\w+\b)).*\(@.*\1.*\)/
```

See [this test code](http://ideone.com/QMzeC).

Answer (score 2):

you can do this quite easily using back references:

```
/(.*).*\(@ \1 \)/
```

Here the `\1` is a reference to what was captured in the unescaped parentheses above.

Your syntax may vary slightly depending on the engine. Perl, sed, vim etc all have slight differences in this area.  For instance, you may have to escape the `@`:

```
/(.*).*\(\@ \1 \)/
```

Or the capturing parentheses may need to be escaped:

```
/\(.*\).*(@ \1 )/
```

In Perl it is recommended to use `$1` instead of `\1`:

```
/(.*).*\(@ $1 \)/
```

Play with it and you'll probably find the correct combination.

Answer (score 1):

This may do what you want:

```
(.+).*\(@.*\1.*\)
```

It will match only if some string exists both outside and inside of `(@ ...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as requested. However, as always with requirements, I forgot an example. It should also match on '(@ abc ) abc', and that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that regex **are not capable of what you are asking**. Your test look like a test to perform on a tree, so you need something more powerful like a parser, which will indeed turn your string into a tree on which you can run your test.

To this purpose see parsers like [ANTLR](http://antlr.org). There are others but this is one of the most famous that we use.

**Edit**: examples that might not be correctly matched by regexes: `(@ abc) (@ abc)` should not match, but I don't see a regex which can distinguish it with `abc (@ abc)` which matches.

Comment: The specification in the question didn't say that `(@ abc) (@ abc)` should not match.

Comment: the OP edited the question and it should not, as I interpreted it (although I agree it was not very obvious)

Comment: regardless, you can still match this using a regex with positive and negative lookaheads.